# Implementing ExpectJ on Python Script

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, expect

I have a Python script named age.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#file: age.py

age = raw_input("Enter your age: ")
print "Your age in dog years is", float(age)/7
```

and I am using the Expectj library, this is the java snippet which I am using

```
ExpectJ exp = new ExpectJ();
Spawn s = null;
try {
    s = exp.spawn(test1);       
    s.expect("Enter your age: ");
    System.out.println("Current status: "+s.getCurrentStandardOutContents());
    s.send("y\n");
} catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ioe\n");
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("toe\n");
} finally {
         if (s != null) 
         s.stop();           
}
```

This is not catching the sysout message `"Enter your age: "` and hence the script goes into an infinite wait state. What fix is required for ExpectJ to work with python script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ExpectJ, but I would guess it's expecting a line terminated with a new line, which `raw_input` does not produce.  From the [raw_input documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input):

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline.

Comment: I didnt put a newline in the match